# In cloud formation how to associate Trusted entities with identity providers for an IAM role

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create IAM roles which will be used by Azure AD to managed sso..

I have create a cft with IAM Roles now i want the to be associated to only to Saml identity provider that i have created.

```
{
    "Resources": {
      "FullAdminXME": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
        "Properties": {
            "Description" : "SAML Role for Azure AD SSO",
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
              {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                  "Service": [
                    "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                  ]
                },
                "Action": [
                  "sts:AssumeRole"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "ManagedPolicyArns": [
            "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess"           
          ]
        }
      },
```

And also is there a way in which i can create saml identity provider using cloud formation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_saml.html

sample arn of an identity provider

```
arn:aws:iam::123456789012:saml-provider/MyUniversity</SAMLProviderArn>
```

I only want to be bounded to to saml Identity provider.

```
 "Statement": [
              {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                  "Service": [
                    "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                  ]
                },
                "Action": [
                  "sts:AssumeRole"
                ]
              }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out see below code

```html
    "Resources": {
      "FullAdminXME": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
        "Properties": {
            "Description" : "SAML Role for Azure AD SSO",
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": 
              {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                  "Federated": { "Ref" : "SAMLID" }
                },
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML",
                "Condition": {
                  "StringEquals": {
                    "SAML:aud": "https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"
                  }
                }
              }
            
          },
          "ManagedPolicyArns": [
            "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess"           
          ]
        }
```